# Scheme Lisp program for the sum of n even numbers

Tags: numbers, scheme, lisp, racket, r5rs

I need to make a function that computes the sum of the first n even numbers starting with 0 (i.e `(even-sum 4)` would return 12).

```
  (define (even-sum n)
    (cond
      ((= n 0) 0)
      ((= n 1) 0)
      (else (+ (* n 2) (even-sum (- n 2 ))))))
```

This is what I have thus far, it works for `(even-sum 4)` but not other cases, `(even-sum 6)` should be 30 but comes out to 24, `(even-sum 2)` should be 2 but comes out to 4.

Comment: Why are you subtracting 2 in the recursion?

Comment: `(define (even-sum n) (* n (- n 1)))`

Comment: Lisp, Scheme, and Racket are three different languages. Please don't tag-bomb.

Answer (score 2):

You can compute the sum of the first *n* numbers of an arithmetic progression by applying this formula (see [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic_progression#Sum)):

```
(define (arithmetic-series step n)
  (let ((an (+ 2 (* step (- n 1)))))
    (/ (* (+ 2 an) n) 2)))

(arithmetic-series 2 20)
=> 420
```

However, if you substitute `d` by 2, the formula is simpler.

*(edit: see [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48569702/scheme-lisp-program-for-the-sum-of-n-even-numbers/48570416#comment84136990_48569702) from  Will Ness)*

Comment: It is sad that, almost certainly, what the instructor is after is precisely the crappy iterative solution that mathematicians have spent so much work showing you can replace by this elegant closed-form solution.  Nevertheless this, of course, is the right answer

Comment: @tfb The best answers to homework questions IMHO are the one an instructor does not want to see: the student cannot simply copy-paste it, and might even learn a thing or two.

Comment: In the days of comp.lang.lisp I had a mild specialisation in answers to homework questions like this.  'OK, the question is looking for a recursive function, let's build an answer using the Y combinator...'

Comment: it was a half-joking comment of course... the point of the exercise is for a student to get comfortable with list manipulations and recursion; it's not their fault that the exercise is not fully thought-out. I wonder what would the reaction be if they turned out *that* code. :)

Answer (score 1):

You should only be subtracting `1` in the recursion step.

And you need to subtract `1` from `n` when multiplying by 2. The first 4 even numbers are `0, 2, 4, 6`, so to get `6` you need `(* (- 4 1) 2)`.

```
(define (even-sum n)
  (cond
   ((= n 0) 0)
   ((= n 1) 0)
   (else (+ (* (- n 1) 2) (even-sum (- n 1))))))
```